# Difference He didn't buy "that" car VS He didn't buy the/a car? (grammar issue)

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

"that" when I have to use "that" in the simple sentence and what's different between "that" or "the/a" with

> He didn't buy "that" car

and

> He didn't buy the/a car

Ps: Please give me more example or any reference URL
Thanks

Comment: This is such a basic concept that I'm curious how it works in your native language.  How do you differentiate objects in space, for example **this** car vs. **that** car vs. **a** car?  Would you use the same article for all three?

Comment: @Andrew I guess my problem could be "Clause sentence" with "That", because I see a lot of sentences to use "that" in the end of sentence like "I want that car" but i don't know what's different between it and "I want a car"<--meaning I want any car. or "I want the car "<--- meaning for specific car . thanks

Comment: *That* car is the one that you see in front of you. You see one. Imagine we are talking and I say *I want that car*. Then you ask *which car?* and I point to a car and say "*that* one." Or if you say simply *I want a car* I might ask "what car do you want?" Then you show me a picture of a car on a Web site. Then you say *this* one. Since the picture is very close to you, *this* might seem more fitting than *that*. However, since the picture represents something far away, you could also say *that* car in that situation as well.

Comment: @willie  "he didn't buy **that** car" is not a clause use of "that".  It's just a basic indication of which car I might mean.   If you want to know how to distinguish between "that" as an article, and "that" as a subordinate conjunction, then please edit your question to include that information.  Otherwise any basic English dictionary should tell you what "that" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a car**

This asks your listener to consider some car in their imagination. You don't know which one. It could be any car.

> I want **a** new car.
>
> If I had **a** car, I wouldn't have to walk.
>
> I need to borrow **a** car to transport the piano.

**the car**

Once you have a particular car in mind, you say *the car*.

> Alice: May I borrow **your car**?
>
> Bob: Sure.
>
> (time passes)
>
> Bob: Here are the keys to **the** car.

In this conversation, Alice identifies a car, and now Alice and Bob both have a particular car in mind. So Bob says "the" car to refer to the particular car under discussion.

**this car**

To refer to something close to you, in your hand, etc. use *this*.

> Alice is holding a magazine with pictures.
>
> Alice: I want to buy **this** car.
>
> Bob: What car?
>
> Alice points to a car.
>
> Alice: Look. **This** one.

**that car**

To refer to something farther away than *this*, or to make a distinction between a *this* reference, use *that*:

Situation 1 - to distinguish between this and that

> Alice: I want to buy **this** car.
>
> Bob: What car?
>
> Alice: Look. **This** one.
>
> Bob: What? **This** one here?
>
> Alice: No, no. Not *that* one. *This* one.

Situation 2 - to refer to something in a conversation

> Alice: I want to buy a car.
>
> Bob: What car?
>
> Alice: A *Dodge Nitro*.
>
> Bob: **That** car is not good.